# C++/Qt: drawing a caret

Tags: c++, qt, caret, paint

I'm learning Qt. I just started to write a text editor from scratch by inheriting QAbstractScrollArea. I'm doing this just for practice. But now I'm faced with the problem of displaying a caret. What comes to my mind is `painter.drawLine` and `QTimer`. Can you give some advices on this. I would also be glad hear some strategies to implement block and underscore caret.

Off Topic: Is this a bug? StackOverflow says there are two answers for this question but I'm seeing only one!

Comment: I've noticed that bug too. My profile page will say that someone has answered, even giving a username that posted it, but I won't see the actual answer for a couple of days sometimes! I'd really like to know why that is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take at a look at paintEvent() in [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html). It has a timer that toggles the cursor on and off. The real cursor drawing is done via [QTextLayout::drawCursor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextlayout.html#drawCursor-2).

For a text editor in general, have a look at [QPlainTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html) and [QTextEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextedit.html).